# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Below is the code I am trying to use to connect to a database and view reports in the JasperViewer.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     try {
         String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
         String username = "user";
         String password = "pwd";
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
         String reportPath = "C:\\path\\extention.jrxml";
         JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);
         JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, con);
         JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
         con.close();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Jasper, but I assume it has a dependency on Apache Commons Log Framework, so you probably need to add Apache Commons Logging to your classpath.

See: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html

Comment: thank you for your kindly answer but it not work to add apache to my classpath

Comment: @Mahmoud Ah, thats okay, but looks like you will need something that ties in with the logging framework. That could be Log4J, SLF4J, or Logback.

Comment: the problem solved by downloading commons-collections4-4.1